# Checking if a console application is still running using the Process class

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm making an application that will monitor the state of another process and restart it when it stops responding, exits, or throws an error.
However, I'm having trouble to make it reliably check if the process (Being a C++ Console window) has stopped responding.

My code looks like this:

```
       public void monitorserver()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            server.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(textbox_srcdsexe.Text, startstring);
            server.Start();
            log("server started");
            log("Monitor started.");
            while (server.Responding)
            {
                if (server.HasExited)
                {
                    log("server exitted, Restarting.");
                    break;
                }
                log("server is running: " + server.Responding.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            log("Server stopped responding, terminating..");
            try
            { server.Kill(); }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

The application I'm monitoring is Valve's Source Dedicated Server, running Garry's Mod, and I'm over stressing the physics engine to simulate it stopping responding.
However, this never triggers the process class recognizing it as 'stopped responding'.

I know there are ways to directly query the source server using their own protocol, but i'd like to keep it simple and universal (So that i can maybe use it for different applications in the future).

Any help appreciated

Comment: +1 for SLaks, the best you can manage is "is it running, or has it stopped?". I'd go for using the proprietary api to check status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Responding` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx) indicates whether the process is running a *Windows message loop* which isn't hung.
As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx) states,

> If the process does not have a MainWindowHandle, this property returns true.

It is not possible to check whether an arbitrary process is doing an arbitrary thing, as you're trying to.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that, and couldn't find it on google ^^; must look better next time. Is there another way to check for a console application if it's hung? thanks for the help =)

Comment: @Ced: There is no conception of a console process being hung.  A console process is always doing something; it may be doing things that allow it to respond to requests.

Comment: @Ced: Not at all.  There is no way to specify a loop, let alone find the right one or check whether it's looping.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info, i guess i'll be using the srcds query system then =)